# Android WebView crashes when variable is set by loadUrl

Tags: javascript, android, webview, crash

following problem makes me go crazy, I have following simple App Code (The Webview exists an the index.html is successfully loaded until I try to read the Variable xmlData wether so or within the HTML Files Javascript. And I am not getting why!

```
public class Boot extends Activity {
WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_boot);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);        
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {  
        @Override  
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result)  
        {
            alert(message);            
            result.confirm();
            return true;    
        }; 
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); 
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:xmlData = \"<apps><app name='Selfhtml' link='http://selfhtml.com'></app></apps>\";alert(xmlData);");
}

public void alert(String msg) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(msg)
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alertdialog = builder.create();
    alertdialog.show();
}
}
```

So can anybody tell me why this crashs? And how to prevent it. (Without using JavaScriptInterface).

It happens even if I wait until the Webview is done with loading the HTML (which is done in a millisecond).

It doesn't crash if I dont read or use the xmlData variable.

Thanks, in Advance

Android Error Message:

```
02-11 23:29:28.581: E/AndroidRuntime(13455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 23:29:28.581: E/AndroidRuntime(13455): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-11 23:29:28.581: E/AndroidRuntime(13455):    at de.appdesigners.androidapp.Boot    $1.onJsAlert(Boot.java:34)
02-11 23:29:28.581: E/AndroidRuntime(13455):    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:704)
02-11 23:29:28.581: E/AndroidRuntime(13455):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 23:29:28.581: E/AndroidRuntime(13455):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
02-11 23:29:28.581: E/AndroidRuntime(13455):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5777)
02-11 23:29:28.581: E/AndroidRuntime(13455):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 23:29:28.581: E/AndroidRuntime(13455):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-11 23:29:28.581: E/AndroidRuntime(13455):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
02-11 23:29:28.581: E/AndroidRuntime(13455):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
02-11 23:29:28.581: E/AndroidRuntime(13455):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you support your question with Log Cat?

Comment: See my edit. It seems theres a Pointer problem but there are no real pointers in Scriptlanguages like Javascript ....

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920770/androidhow-to-add-support-the-javascript-alert-box-in-webviewclient or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892644/android-webview-after-onjsalert-not-responding-taps . So, you should put your AlertDialog in `onJsAlert` function . hope this helps

Comment: Thx, I actually use a WebChromeClient(I didn't post it in order to make the code more readable).

Comment: I tried following scenarios: 1. Load offline-page (from asset-folder) a.) trigger JS when webview finished (onPageFinished) b.) trigger JS when webview was loading 2.) Load online-page a.) + b.) as under 1.) described...All scenarios worked, no NPE nor Error onConsoleMessage...